# How to handle empty space on enter key press in flex?

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

I am trying to create a pattern like below, for ,when enter button is pressed twice, the program should terminate, but if user enters something in the line, the program shouldn't  terminate.

```
[\n\n]  {
if( strcmp(yytext,"?")){
            return 0;
         }   
}
```

I try to check with strcmp for yytex is null space, but what should ı put inside " " ?

Comment: `\n` represents a newline, not a tab.

Comment: Since Flex will execute that rule only when it matches a pair of consecutive newlines, why do you think that `yytext` might in that rule be observed to contain anything other than a pair of consecutive newlines (`"\n\n"`)?  But since you already know what `yytext` must contain, I don't see the point of checking it.

Comment: Thanks, i dont know what can i compare with, it is enter button for getting newline at terminal

Comment: The point is that Flex is doing the comparison already.  That's what the pattern (`[\n\n]`) is about.  You do need to choose that appropriately, but having done so, you know that when the rule is triggered, the contents of `yytext` will match that pattern.  It is redundant to test that again.

Answer (score 2):

`[\n\n]` doesn't match two consecutive line breaks. It's a character class matching a single character that's either a line break or ... a line break. It's equivalent to just `\n` - duplicate elements in a character class have no effect.

To match two consecutive line breaks, what you want is `\n\n` without the bracket.

As for `strcmp`, there is absolutely no reason to check the contents of `yytext` here. Using the pattern `[\n\n]`, `yytext` can only ever be equal to `"\n"` and using `\n\n`, it can only ever be equal to `"\n\n"`. Either way there's no reason to compare it to anything when you already know what its value is going to be.

Comment: Okke, what is your advice

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for this situation guys

```
^\n               yyterminate();
```